# Why is my thread the MainThread?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, raspberry-pi3

I'm creating 5 threads for handling various tasks such as reading from sensors (Raspberry Pi), TCP connections and recently recording audio (pyAudio).

I am instantiating all threads in main() identically e.g.:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

def main():
    global network_thread
    network_thread = threading.Thread(name="NET-CONN", target=network_thread_run, args=())
    network_thread.start()
```

I keep a global reference so I can kill the threads at shutdown with join().

Now, I have added thread #5:

```
global audio_thread
audio_thread = threading.Thread(name="AUDIO", target=audio_thread_run(), args=())
audio_thread.start()
```

...but my logging indicates it's running on the MainThread. I also double-checked inside the audio_thread_run() function and it is indeed running on MainThread:

```
if threading.current_thread() is threading.main_thread():
    logger.warning("Audio thread is the same as MainThread!")
```

Why is this thread running on the MainThread? Have I hit a limit on the Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at the two places where you create threads, modified slightly so they'll fit on one line, and with white-space inserted so they line up:

```
net_thread = threading.Thread(name="NET", target=net_run  , args=())
aud_thread = threading.Thread(name="AUD", target=aud_run(), args=())
# Hmmm, what's this suspicious-looking thing here? ---->^^
```

Enough fun :-) The problem is that you are actually *calling* the `audio_thread_run()` function directly from your main thread and presumably, if it ever returned, you would then try to use the result as a callable to start a thread.

If you actually got rid of the thread start stuff altogether, it would boil down to the much simpler:

```
audio_thread_run()
```

which will *very much* run that function from the context of the main thread.

What you need to do is to *remove* the parentheses so it matches what you've down with the network threads:

```
audio_thread = threading.Thread(name="AUDIO", target=audio_thread_run, args=())
```

Comment: Let future readers beware - the appended () were automatically inserted by IntellliJ after copying the line and using auto-suggest to insert the function name.

Comment: @glenneroo, that's very annoying. QtCreator does the same thing (if you type in `auto x  = somefunc<tab>`) - it auto-completes with parentheses. Note that VisualStudio (2105) doesn't do this - it auto-completes only the name. I'm not usually a Microsoft fan-boy but at least they got this bit right :-)